# PyQt5: Cannot style classes from different file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I am making my own classes extended from QWidget. When the style and class is in same file there is no problem with styling it.

*main.py*

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from widgets import HistoryWidget, RandomBtn


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        hw = HistoryWidget()
        btn = RandomBtn()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(hw)
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 400)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    stylesheet = """

   MainWindow {
       background-color: #1c1c1c;
   }

   HistoryWidget {
       background-color: #cadd45;
   }

   QLabel {
        color: white;
   }

   RandomBtn {
       background-color: #cadd45;
   }

   """
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    app.exec()
```

However, when the class is from different file it seems to not find that element (class) in styling

*widgets.py*

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class HistoryWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QGridLayout())
        l = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello")
        self.layout().addWidget(l)
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))


class RandomBtn(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
```

You can see that the button is affected, but the widget is not.
Any idea what to do with that? Thanks

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, it generates errors so it is recommended that you correct it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Code is fixed and i even did better example :-)

Comment: @AdamŠtursa I can see the stylesheet correctly applied. If you don't, please provide a screenshot of the result *using the code you provided in the example*.

Comment: @musicamante [https://imgur.com/a/fHuXn9I](https://imgur.com/a/fHuXn9I) in this post is image of my result and image of my expectation

Comment: @AdamŠtursa and if you put everything in one single file (again, using the provided example code), it works? Sorry to ask again, but you say "expectation" and I'm not sure if  you mean "it should behave like this" or "if I put the code all in a single file it shows this".